# Owl Carousel 2- sliding without stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, owl-carousel-2

I have a carousel slider with logos. In works fine except I am not so sure how to stop the "stopping/delaying" of the slider.

What I want to achieve is a non-stopping slide, without any delay. Something like this: https://codepen.io/altos/pen/jzqoPW

My current code:

```
$("#mini-slider").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    navText: false,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    lazyLoad:true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 1000,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        400:{
            items:2
        },
        450:{
            items:2
        },
        500:{
            items:2
        },
        550:{
            items:2
        },
        651:{
            items:2
        },
        991:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/altos/pen/dmMEWw

Comment: Why not just use the code from the codepen you linked to? Owl Carousel is for carousels, I would not call what you are trying to achieve a carousel.

Comment: I know, that would be easy part. But I want to know how to solve it with Owl Carousel.